# Combining relevance sorting with word prefix searching in ArangoDb?

Tags: arangodb

In ArangoDB, I'm using a search view that sorts results using [BM25](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/views-arango-search.html#bm25), something like:

```
FOR doc IN someView
SEARCH ANALYZER(doc.description == 'foo', 'text_en')
SORT BM25(doc)
RETURN doc
```

This only performs full word searching though (i.e. will not match documents containing e.g. "foot", "a football"), so I'd like to use word prefix searching instead.

I know this can be done with FULLTEXT indexes, e.g.:

```
FOR doc IN FULLTEXT(someCollection, "description", "prefix:foo")
RETURN doc
```

but then I lose the relevance sorting.

Is there a way to combine both of these so that I can perform partial word matching, but also get results ordered by relevance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `STARTS_WITH` function, e.g.

```
FOR doc IN someView
SEARCH ANALYZER(STARTS_WITH(doc.description, 'foo'), 'text_en')
SORT BM25(doc)
RETURN doc
```

For more functions supported by ArangoSearch please check the documentation:
https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/views-arango-search.html

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly. I'd seen the function, but misunderstood that it would only search for the whole field's prefix, rather than per token.